# Direct Sum of Subrepresentations

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G=C_p=\langle x\rangle$ and $R=\mathbb{F}_p$ where $p\geq 3$ is a prime. $\rho$ is a representation satisfying $\rho(x)=\begin{bmatrix}
     1&1&1\\
     0&1&0\\
     0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$. Show that this representation is the direct sum of two non-zero representations.

Possible subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_p^3$ are $\{a_1e_1|a_1\in\mathbb{F}_p\}$, $\{a_2e_2|a_2\in\mathbb{F}_p\}$, $\{a_3e_3|a_3\in\mathbb{F}_p\}$, $\{a_1e_1+a_2e_2|a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{F}_p\}$, $\{a_1e_1+a_3e_3|a_1,a_3\in\mathbb{F}_p\}$, $\{a_2e_2+a_3e_3|a_2,a_3\in\mathbb{F}_p\}$ and $\mathbb{F}_p^3$. The only proper invariant subspace are $\{a_1e_1|a_1\in\mathbb{F}_p\}$, $\{a_1e_1+a_2e_2|a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{F}_p\}$, $\{a_1e_1+a_3e_3|a_1,a_3\in\mathbb{F}_p\}$. But the direct sum of any two of them is not $\mathbb{F}_p^3$. I don't see why the representation is the direct sum of two non-trivial subrepresentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathbb F_p^3=\mathrm{span}\{e_1,e_2\}\oplus\mathrm{span}\{e_2-e_3\}.$$